# Displaying only certain text from file - Visual Basic

Tags: visual-studio, vba

I want to only display numbers in a text box that i have. At the moment my code reads the text file and adds all the code to the textbox and not only the needed text(which are numbers).

```
    tbRecipient.Text = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("filepath")
```

if anyone can point me in the right direction and let me know how i would go around this problem, that would be great.

I have a file containing:

```
Steve, 017876
Alan, 098578
...
```

I want to list only the numbers into a text box once i have got them from the file. 
To do this i am using:

```
Dim i As Integer

    For i = 0 To cbRecipients.CheckedItems.Count - 1
        My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("filepath", cbRecipients.CheckedItems.Item(i) & vbCrLf, True)
    Next
    frmHome.myFunction()
```

Then under myFunction() is:
    tbRecipient.Text = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("filepath")

Comment: Show us the text you are reading and the numbers you want to extract on using a small Representative sample. You could use Parse or string functins such as substring/Mid to get the text you want out of the file.

Comment: The text i am reading is .... User a, 001, sales.    User b, 024, project.    user c, 087, technical.

Comment: Each line contains the name and the number like... bob, 002 (next line) steve, 085 (next line...)

Comment: Im using VBA. Jays code didnt look that similar to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function:

```
Function GetFileColumnContents(s_Path As String, ColumnNumber As Long, ColumnDelimiter As String, Optional s_OutputDelimiter As String) As String

On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    Open s_Path For Input As #1     'Open the txt file for readin as Temporary File Number 1
    Do While Not EOF(1)             'Read line bu line until end of file
        Line Input #1, Mystring     'Store the line value in Mystring
        GetFileColumnContents = GetFileColumnContents & s_OutputDelimiter & Split(Mystring, ColumnDelimiter)(ColumnNumber - 1) 'process the string
    Loop
ErrHandler:
    Close #1

End Function
```

Call in subrutine:

```
tbRecipient.Text = GetFileColumnContents("filepath", 2, ",", vbCrLf)
```

Edit: The *linenum = linenum + 1*  was not neccesary in the function (edited above)

s_Path : is path to the txt file (like "C:\Test.txt")

ColumnNumber: is the column in the text file. If the data looks like:

- A, 123, red
- B, 456, blue

then ColumnNumber 1 are letters, ColumnNumber 2 are numbers and 3 are colors.

(ColumnNumber - 1) is there because first part of split has index 0, but the ColumnNumber is 1

```
split("A, 123, red",",")(0) 'results to "A"
split("A, 123, red",",")(1) 'results to " 123"
```

If you want to list the items from text file column 2 and in the result separated by comma then call the function with comma as last argument:

```
tbRecipient.Text = GetFileColumnContents("filepath", 2, ",", ",")
```

Comment: Suggestion to add Option Explicit and to define the variables. Also, what is (ColumnNumber - 1) for?

Comment: Im Not Using ColumnNumber 1. basically what i want to do is extract only the number(001, 002, ect) from the text file leaving the characters(User a, User b, ect) in the text file. The with the numbers i want to list them in a textbox(001, 002, 097, ect).

Comment: Dont understand whats going on for, s_Path, Line Input #1. Im persuming that mystring is a string and linenum is an integer. Sorry im still learning all of this.